# Geolocation inside promise [ionic 2]

Tags: android, geolocation, angular, ionic2

We have implemented the geolocation call inside a promise, using Ionic 2. It works as expected on iOS and older versions of Android.

We're performing the geolocation call inside the app.js file, and we’re resolving it in the first view.

Under Android Marshmallow (our problematic platform here), we get permission-related errors until the user accepts the permissions dialog. So far, so good. However, once the user accepts the permissions, the errors keep happening, but are instead timeout errors.

We’d expect the plugin to return coordinates when called after being granted permissions by the user, instead it is returning a timeout error. This does not happen if the app is force closed and then open again, as the plugin returns coordinates as expected.

Is this a known issue? Is there a known workaround?
ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did :)

//geolocation-service.js (provider)

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class GeolocationService {
    constructor(){
        this.coords = null;
    }

    // Si da timeout, mostrar un error visual en el app
    // Si tocas ese error (tap), reintenta cargar datos
    geolocate() {
        var geoOptions = {timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

        if (this.coords) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.coords);
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    resolve(position);
                }, 
                (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                }, geoOptions
            );  
        })
    }
    getCoords() {
        return this.geolocate().then(
            position => {
                return position;
            }).then(error => {
                return error;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use (inside a platform.ready()!):

```
this.geolocationService.geolocate();
this.geolocationService.getCoords().then(
    (position) => {
         //use you coords here   
    }, (error) => {}
);
```

Comment: Any ideas why i'd be getting Error TS2339: Property 'coords' does not exist on type 'GeoLocationService'.
?

Comment: Also, if I try this with the Geolocation plugin I get : Error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.